# Javascript, ограничения в input

Tags: javascript, input

как установить ограничение для количества слов в input[type="text"]. Например, количество слов введенных через запятую не превышало 10.

Comment: Использование JS для этой задачи не совсем подходит. Лучше использовать HTML5-решение. Использовать JS стоит только если вам надо поддерживать устаревшие браузеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чего проще - при событии `keyup` на поле считать количество запятых и, если их больше, чем надо, то пишем ошибку и/или блокируем поле.
Пример:

```js
(function() {
  var max = 5,
      count = 0,
      input = null,
      result = null;
  
  function init(){
    input = document.querySelector('#inp');
    result = document.querySelector('#count');
    
    input.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
  }

  function keyup(e){
    if((count = getNumOfComma(this.value)) >= max){
      result.innerHTML = '<strong>Превышен лимит на запятые!</strong>'; // Лимит превышен
    }else{
      result.innerHTML = count; // Всё пучком, пиши дальше
    }
  }
  
  function getNumOfComma(value){
    var ch, i = 0;
    
    for(ch in value){
      ch = value[ch];
      
      if(ch == ',' || ch == ',')
        i++;
    }
    
    return i;
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
}());
```

```html
<input type='text' id='inp' />
<br />
<span id='count'>0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<style>
  input:invalid { outline: 5px solid red; }
</style>

<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^([^,]+(,|$)){1,10}$" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```